# Recursively set all files and folders to 777 from this list

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, operating-system

I've tried endlessly searching for a solution to this, but couldn't seem to find out.

I have a list of paths:

```
dirToModify = ['includes/','misc/','modules/','scripts/','themes/']
```

I want to loop through each list-item (a dir in this case) and set all files and dirs to `777`

I've done this for files like:

```
for file in fileToModify:
    os.chmod(file, 0o777)
```

But can't seem to figure out a good way to do this recursively to folders.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can iterate through the directories you'd like to modify, then use `os.walk` to iterate over all of the directories and files in each of these directories, like so:

```
for your_dir in dirs_to_modify:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_dir):
        for d in dirs:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root, d), 0o777)
        for f in files:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root, f), 0o777)
```

Comment: this won't work as you are not joining the paths

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, you're right - editing now.

Comment: Is it possible to do:  os.remove(d) too?

Comment: @CodeTalk To remove a directory? You'd probably want to use shutil.rmtree: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree