# Reverting root folder ownership ubuntu

Tags: root, python-3.4, ubuntu-16.04, ownership

I just use the answer of
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980289/recursively-set-all-files-and-folders-to-777-from-this-list#) and now all the folders in root have different permissions and I can't use some programs like Chromium, terminal, etc.

I just replace dirs_to_modify by /home/my_user/.hidden_folder

Also, I should state that I ran the script as root using sudo.

I feel like I broke my Ubuntu OS.
Help please.

Comment: What errors do you see? We are not sure what permissions you may have changed. If you specify errors, that may give a clue. The post you referred to changes permissions to 777. That would be a security risk, but still your commands should still work. If you have another system, you could compare permissions for few fies.

Comment: I cant just open the programs. It show the window error "Ubuntu has experimented an internal error" (something like that). Also, all the folder icon inside root are marked by a "X".

Comment: Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300557/how-to-restore-the-default-chown-permissions-on-a-directory-file) for related discussion. You may get better answers by asking your question in askubuntu site.

Comment: Most likely the recursive chmod command followed up the directories back to root partition (through the double-dot link) and modified the permissions for all dirs/files there. It would help if you specify what exact command you ran, also mention the directory in which you ran the commands.

Comment: Im resigned to reinstall my OS. :'( Thanks for your time, dude

Comment: Don't worry. Everybody goes through at least one of these _accidents_. That is how we learn. Recursive remove, recursive chmod, the accidents that happen during recursive find & move files .... Good luck with new installation.